# How to generate multiple mixins (mixin lib) with loop in sass

Tags: sass

I would like to keep my sass code short.

instead of

```
@mixin tg($font-size,$line-height) {
  something related to font-size and line-height
}

@mixin h1 {
  @include tg 
}

@mixin h2 {
  @include tg 
}

....
```

How can i create a @mixin lib with loop?

```
$typography-list: h1, h2......
@mixin tg($font-size,$line-height) {
  something related to font-size and line-height
}


@each $typography in $typography-list {
  create @mixin {
    @include tg()
  }
}
```

if so, what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: You can't create mixin that way, SASS compile into CSS not in another SASS. Why you need h1, h2, etc be mixins?

Comment: I am trying to create a lib, so it can be shared cross project without creating any css. The css render part would be in different sass file

Comment: ok, but if you don't compile, how can you run the loop to get the mixins? I don't understand

Comment: I don't think sass can, and that is my question. i need help to achieve this with sass feature (create mixins in loop)

Comment: Update: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2146

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you are referring to `SCSS` producing `SCSS`. This is called as **meta-programming**. It is not possible in `SASS`. Unless SASS invents some technique or you have another language that compiles to `SCSS`.

In short, currently, you cannot do that.