# How to create list of vars in loop?

Tags: sass

I have a main colour #abc

and we can create colour with darken with percentage

how can i create list of darken colours with a loop?

```
@mixin create-color($main) {
  create some vars 
} 

@include create-color(blue);
```

i will get

```
$c-green-1: green
$c-green-2: (green-lighten 10%)
$c-green-3: (green-lighten 20%)
```

Comment: SASS compile into CSS, you can't generate variables from a mixin

Comment: Your question reminded me of another, and also was yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380955/how-to-generate-multiple-mixins-mixin-lib-with-loop-in-sass. Far as I know there is no way to do that

Comment: thanks, blonfu. :), that one is mine as well

Answer (score 0):

This will accomplish what you're after:

```
@mixin alphaColor($name,$color) {
   @for $i from 1 through 10 {
      .c-#{$name}-#{$i} { 
        color: rgba($color,$i/10); 
      }
    }
}

@include alphaColor("blue",blue);
@include alphaColor("red",#ed1414);
@include alphaColor("absurd",rgb(20,237,20));
```

This is a mixin that will take a color (named, hex, rgb), and loop thru it creating named (you give it an initial name) color declarations in RGBA with alpha from .1 - 1 incrementing by .1.

**Output above would be:**

```
.c-blue-1 { color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1); }
.c-blue-2 { color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2); }
.c-blue-3 { color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3); }
.c-blue-4 { color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4); }
.c-blue-5 { color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5); }
.c-blue-6 { color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.6); }
.c-blue-7 { color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7); }
.c-blue-8 { color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8); }
.c-blue-9 { color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9); }
.c-blue-10 { color: blue; }
.c-red-1 { color: rgba(237, 20, 20, 0.1); }
.c-red-2 { color: rgba(237, 20, 20, 0.2); }
.c-red-3 { color: rgba(237, 20, 20, 0.3); }
.c-red-4 { color: rgba(237, 20, 20, 0.4); }
.c-red-5 { color: rgba(237, 20, 20, 0.5); }
.c-red-6 { color: rgba(237, 20, 20, 0.6); }
.c-red-7 { color: rgba(237, 20, 20, 0.7); }
.c-red-8 { color: rgba(237, 20, 20, 0.8); }
.c-red-9 { color: rgba(237, 20, 20, 0.9); }
.c-red-10 { color: #ed1414; }
.c-absurd-1 { color: rgba(20, 237, 20, 0.1); }
.c-absurd-2 { color: rgba(20, 237, 20, 0.2); }
.c-absurd-3 { color: rgba(20, 237, 20, 0.3); }
.c-absurd-4 { color: rgba(20, 237, 20, 0.4); }
.c-absurd-5 { color: rgba(20, 237, 20, 0.5); }
.c-absurd-6 { color: rgba(20, 237, 20, 0.6); }
.c-absurd-7 { color: rgba(20, 237, 20, 0.7); }
.c-absurd-8 { color: rgba(20, 237, 20, 0.8); }
.c-absurd-9 { color: rgba(20, 237, 20, 0.9); }
.c-absurd-10 { color: #14ed14; }
```

SASSmeister demo: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/39577ef556de22a9acfe934cbc108a4e

Comment: Thanks for the help, Robert. I knew how to do that, what i am creating is a lib for multiple projects. Ideally, import this lib should not generate any css